# How to handle the AuthenticityToken value using a HTTP POST request from a RoR application to another RoR application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, ruby-on-rails-3, authenticity-token

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to know how to handle the AuthenticityToken value using a HTTP POST request from a RoR application to another RoR application. In this case I aim to submit a sign in form and return the user information in *JSON* format if he\she provided correct `email` and `password` values.

I have a RoR application at this URL

```
pjtnam.com
```

and another RoR application at this URL

```
users.pjtname.com
```

If I make an HTTP POST request from the application `pjtname.com` to the application `users.pjtname.com` like this (in this example I use the [Typhoeus gem](https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus))

```
response = Typhoeus::Request.post("http://users.pjtname.com/authentications",
             :params => {
               :new_authentication => {
                 :email    => email,
                 :password => password
               }
             }
           )
```

I get this response

```
<h1>
  ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
    in AuthenticationsController#create
</h1>
<pre>ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken</pre>
```

So, **how to handle the AuthenticityToken value in a safe approach\mode?** *I would like to know in both when applications are located on the same server and when they aren't.*

At `http://users.pjtname.com/authentications/new` I have the following form for signing in users:

```
<%= form_for(:new_authentication) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.label :password %>

  <%= f.submit "Sign in" %>
<% end %>
```

In the authentications_controller.rb I have

```
def create
  # Note ':authentication' symbol is different than ':new_authentication' seen in HTTP POST parameters and in the above form
  @authentication = Authentication.new(params[:authentication])

  @account = Account.sign_in_account(params[:new_authentication][:email], params[:new_authentication][:password])

  ...

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {
      redirect_to @account
    }
    format.js {
      render(:update) { |page|
        page.redirect_to @account
      }
    }
    format.json {
      render :json => @account
    }
  end
end
```

In routes.rb I have

```
  resources :authentications do #, :path => "authentication" do
    member do
      get  'confirm_authentication'
      post 'confirm_authentication'
    end
  end
```

---

---

**UPDATE** for the **@idlefingers** answer

---

REQUEST

```
Typhoeus::Request.post("http://users.pjtname.com/authentications/new",
# or
# Typhoeus::Request.post("http://users.pjtname.com/authentications",
   :headers => {"Content-Type" => "application/json"},
   :params => { ... } # Same parameters as above
   }
 )
```

RESPONSE

```
<h1>
  StandardError
</h1>
<pre>Invalid JSON string</pre>
```

---

REQUEST

```
Typhoeus::Request.post("http://users.pjtname.com/authentications/new.json",
   :params => { ... } # Same parameters as above
   }
 )
```

RESPONSE

```
<h1>Routing Error</h1>
<p><pre>No route matches &quot;/authentications/new.json&quot;</pre></p>
```

Comment: Are these two hosts running on the same server?

Comment: @Dex I updated the question (at the bottom) in order to respond to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's not sending the request with the correct content type. Rails should skip the authenticity token check if the content-type is application/xml or application/json, so that it plays nice with APIs without having to disable the authenticity token altogether.

I don't know the Typhoeus gem, but it looks like you may need to just add ".json" or ".xml" to the url (depending on the API you've implemented), or may need to pass it in as options in the headers hash.

Comment: I updated the question with some more information: form view and controller code, some test results.

Comment: Can you add your routes? Assuming you're using `resources :authentications`, it would expect the post to go to /authentications.json, not /authentications/new.json. You also need to setup the actions to be able to accept json (using `respond_with` or `respond_to` - see [ActionController::Responder](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html))

Comment: The problem is in sending parameters. If I use this `Typhoeus::Request.post("http://users.pjtname.com/authentications.json?new_authentication[email]=test@test.ts&new_authentication[password]=aaaaaa"` it works, but how can I send parameters using the Typhoeus syntax `:params => {:new_authentication => {:email => email, :password => password}}`?

Comment: I just opened a new question about the above comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156052/trouble-on-thypoeus-and-the-rack-query-string